# Weird behavior with *1

Tags: windows, cmd, wildcard

I wonder about a special behavior of the expression *1 under Windows. I have threesub-folders: "*s1*", "*s2*" and "*a b*". When I type:

```
dir *1
```

it will list "s1" as well as "a b". In fact it will list all folders that have a space in the file name.

```
dir *2
```

works as expected.

Anyone any clue?

Comment: dir also examines legacy 8.3 file names, the space forces an 8.3 alias that contains a "1" - examine `dir *1 /x` to see these names.

Answer (score 2):

Alex K. is correct.

The name `a b` has a space and thus it's treated like a "long" file name.  The system will generate an alternative "short" file name for the benefit of older applications that don't cope with "long" file names. 
 The short name will be an 8.3 name that likely ends in `~1`.  `dir` (and most other programs that do wildcard searches on Windows) will look at both the "long" file name and the "short" one when determining if there is a match.

Comment: Thank you both!
Is there a way to specify the name such that I really get only folders ending "1"?

Comment: @JohannesSchacht: `for /d %a in (*1) do @echo %a`. `/d` returns folders only (command line syntax; for use in a batch file, replace each `%a`with `%%a`) (btw: the wildcard `*` stands for "any number of characters" aka "zero or more". `?` stands for "exactly one" or "zero or one" depending on where it is)

Comment: @JohannesSchacht, I think the best option to ignore the short path is to post-filter the output of `dir` by `findstr`, like this, for instance: `dir /B *1 | findstr /I "^.*1"`. Alternatively, you could use `where`, which ignores the short name: `where ".:*1"` (but this unfortunately regards the `%PATHEXT%` variable)...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using the expression in the Robocopy's /XD parameter. I guess I need to live with the restriction that wildcards of type *<digits> will not work. That's not too bad.